# How to Update Textview text in loop

Tags: android, while-loop, textview

I want to have an extremely simple XML layout with just one textview in it. I want the text view to go up by one every second. To do this I have used this code

```
    public class test extends Activity{
    TextView num;
    int to =0;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.updatexml);
num = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvUpdate);
        startIncrementing();
    }
    public void startIncrementing() {
        while (to < 100) {
            num.setText(to + "");
            to++;
        }
        }
    }
```

Have done a good hour of searching but have not found a good answer. Any help would be great.

Edit:

Used given answers below and got this in the error log:

```
04-15 17:35:17.637: E/AndroidRuntime(28985): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-15 17:35:17.637: E/AndroidRuntime(28985): Process: com.infitenothing.dogcat, PID: 28985
04-15 17:35:17.637: E/AndroidRuntime(28985): java.lang.NullPointerException
04-15 17:35:17.637: E/AndroidRuntime(28985):    at com.infitenothing.word.Test2$1.run(Test2.java:41)
04-15 17:35:17.637: E/AndroidRuntime(28985):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
04-15 17:35:17.637: E/AndroidRuntime(28985):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
04-15 17:35:17.637: E/AndroidRuntime(28985):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
04-15 17:35:17.637: E/AndroidRuntime(28985):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
04-15 17:35:17.637: E/AndroidRuntime(28985):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-15 17:35:17.637: E/AndroidRuntime(28985):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
04-15 17:35:17.637: E/AndroidRuntime(28985):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
04-15 17:35:17.637: E/AndroidRuntime(28985):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
04-15 17:35:17.637: E/AndroidRuntime(28985):    at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:126)
04-15 17:35:17.637: E/AndroidRuntime(28985):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Current Code

```
public class Test2 extends Activity {

    // Init var
    int i=0;
    TextView num;
    final Handler myHandler = new Handler();
    final Timer myTimer = new Timer();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Init your TextView
        num = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvUpdate);

        // Timer
        TimerTask myTask = new TimerTask() {
            public void run() {
                updateUI(); // updateUI method
            }
        };
        myTimer.schedule(myTask,0,1000); // TimerTask, delay, period
    }

    // Runnable method
    final Runnable myRunnable = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            num.setText(String.valueOf(i)); // update your text
        }
    };

    // updateUI method related to a Runnable
    private void updateUI() {
        if(i < 100) {
            i++;
            // num.setText(String.valueOf(i)); = avoid the RunTime error
            myHandler.post(myRunnable); // relate this to a Runnable
        } else {
            myTimer.cancel(); // stop the timer
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create a `Timer` related to a `Runnable` (*to avoid the RunTime error*) which updates the view every second:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    // Init var
    int i=0;
    TextView num;
    final Handler myHandler = new Handler();
    final Timer myTimer = new Timer();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Init your TextView
        num = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textNum);

        // Timer
        TimerTask myTask = new TimerTask() {
            public void run() {
                updateUI(); // updateUI method
            }
        };
        myTimer.schedule(myTask,0,1000); // TimerTask, delay, period
    }

    // Runnable method
    final Runnable myRunnable = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            num.setText(String.valueOf(i)); // update your text
        }
    };

    // updateUI method related to a Runnable
    private void updateUI() {
        if(i < 100) {
            i++;
            // num.setText(String.valueOf(i)); = avoid the RunTime error
            myHandler.post(myRunnable); // relate this to a Runnable
        } else {
            myTimer.cancel(); // stop the timer
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks that what other sources said, the only problem is. Eclipse is giving me an error message from ".schedule" to "; //1" any ideas on why that might be?

Comment: @user2202646 where did you get that? Can you provide more details about your error please?

Comment: Under ".schedule" there is a red line that says "Syntax error on token "schedule", = expected after this token" Then under everthing else in that section of code it says "Syntax error on tokens, ArgumentList expected instead"

Comment: @user2202646 I forgot the TimerTask class, my mistake. This should work now. Let me know.

Comment: That got most of the errors away but now there is an error under the 1000 in "myTimer.schedule(myTask, 100);" that says "Syntax error on tokens, VariableDeclarator expected instead"

Comment: @user22022646 Hum.. Did you copy/paste your code inside your comment? Because in this case, a `0` is missing. :)

Comment: yes I copied it. I was messing around with code to try to fix it though so must have accidentally deleted the 0 at the end.

Comment: re-copied the code, just to see if my tinkering with might have messed it up. Still same problem, under the 1000 there's a red line that says, "Syntax error on tokens, VariableDeclarator expected instead"

Comment: @user2202646 stupid mistake from me `=<` isn't exist in Java.. It's now corrected.

Comment: Noticed that one and fixed it myself but still have problem I stated in prior comment

Comment: @user2202646 It works pretty well for me, let me know if this works for you too and sorry for the delay and the mistakes.

Comment: Sorry still has the same "VariableDeclarator expected instead" error.

Comment: @user2202646 Please provide your code by editing your question... The exact code above works on 2.+ and 4.2+...

Comment: I got ride of the error on my computer by restating computer and the recopying your code. Ran it on 4.4.2 and got a bunch of errors added the errors to the question as well as a copy of my code that I have.

Comment: Never mind it does work. Just forgot to put my xml layout in place of "R.layout.activity_main". Thanks for all the advice Fllo.

Answer (score 0):

Try the CountDownTimer. You can modify the code to make it go up instead. Example can be found here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html